# Android: How persistence is kept while app is killed?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

[Android app guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) suggest that use models separated from  views to have persistence and explains:

> Persistence is ideal for the following reasons:
>
> - Your users don't lose data if the Android OS destroys your app to free up resources.
> - Your app continues to work in cases when a network connection is flaky or not available.

I want to know how app does not lose data even if app is killed?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the practices followed in the architectural patterns. It means that the role of the View(Activity/Fragment) is just to display the data and it should not be able to make the changes to the data directly. This is in return helps us to solve a lot of persistence related issues:
In order to explain more on this let's say you are creating an Instagram like app which lets the currently logged-in user follow/unfollow that user. We want this button to affect the label with the number of followers and to change the text on the button accordingly. 
Let's understand with a code example.

Code:

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    isFollowing = webService.getIsFollowing();
    numberOfFollowers = webService.getNumberOfFollowers();
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleFollow();
        }
    });
}

private void toggleFollow() {
    if (isFollowing)
        unFollow();
    else
        follow();
}

private void unFollow() {
    isFollowing = false;
    numberOfFollowers -= 1;
    followersText.setText(numberOfFollowers + " Followers");
    setNotFollowingButton();
}

private void follow() {
    isFollowing = true;
    numberOfFollowers += 1;
    followersText.setText(numberOfFollowers + " Followers");
    setFollowingButton();
}

private void setFollowingButton() {
    toggleButton.setText("Following");
    toggleButton.setBackground(getLightGreenColor());
}

private void setNotFollowingButton() {
    toggleButton.setText("Follow");
    toggleButton.setBackground(getGreenColor());
}
```

}

**Besides being dirty code it has major flaws**

1. App Components like activities/fragments aren't managed by us, rather than by the Android OS.
2. Their lifecycle isn’t under our control, they can be destroyed at any time based on user interactions or other factors like low memory
3. If we were to create and handle our data in a UI component, all of our data would be destroyed once that component is destroyed.

**In this example, every time the user rotates the device the activity gets destroyed and recreated again, causing all the data members to reset and the network calls to be executed again, wasting the user bandwidth and forcing the user to wait for the new queries to complete. Therefore it is better to avoid the data handling part from the UI**

For more understanding and clarity would suggest you watch this video by Lyla. She explains well with a similar example. Please let me know if you need more clarity
Video Link : [DroidCon Architectural Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlZVYkhoSq8)
Another Helpful Link: [Nice article why persisting on UI is not a good choice](https://medium.com/sears-israel/when-and-why-to-use-android-livedata-93d7dd949138)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The question is how data is not lost even after the app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways to persist data in Android when your app is killed by OS you can choose one them to restore your data or app's state.

- SQLite
- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage

### SQLite

Basically, it is a relational database. You can find more detail in this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). If you choose to use SQLite I suggest you use one of the ORM libraries. The most popular one is Room Persistence Libray from the Android

### Shared Preferences

You can use it for storing key-value data. [More...](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

### External/Internal Storage

Storing files on the device file system. The difference between them is Internal storage is private to your application. External storage lets you store files in the shared file system. 
[Writing files to internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)
[Writing files to external storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage)